# When item is clicked in React native drop down picker it is not selected

Tags: javascript, react-native, drop-down-menu

When item is clicked in React native drop down picker it is not selected, but when I press second time on the same item it is selected. It worked in the start, but don't know what broke it. Can someone help??

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Modal, Pressable} from 'react-native';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import {
    dataBase,
} from "../Firebase/Firebase";


const styles = require('../Graphics/Styles/Styles');

const Readings = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const [city, setCity] = useState(null);
  const [FireCityData, setFireCityData] = useState([]);

  const [FirePumpData, setFirePumpData] = useState([])
  const[pumpState, setPumpState] = useState(true)
  const [pumpData, setPumpData] = useState([])
  const [pump, setPump] = useState(null);

  const [isFocusCity, setIsFocusCity] = useState(false)
  const [isFocusPump, setIsFocusPump] = useState(false)

  const [reading, setReading] = useState(null)

  const getCitiesData =async ()=>{
    exportCitiesData = []
    await dataBase
      .collection("Cities")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(
                    (documentSnapshot) => {
              exportCitiesData.push(
                            documentSnapshot.data()
                        );
                    }
                );
      });
      setFireCityData(exportCitiesData)
  }
  const getPumpData =async ()=>{
    exportPumpData = []
    await dataBase
      .collection("Pumps")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(
                    (documentSnapshot) => {
              exportPumpData.push(
                            documentSnapshot.data()
                        );
                    }
                );
      });
      setFirePumpData(exportPumpData)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getCitiesData()
    getPumpData()
  },[]);

  const getCitysPumps = (city) =>{
    let pumpArray = []
    FirePumpData.forEach(pump => {
      if(pump.city == city.label){
        pumpArray.push(pump)
      }
    });
    setPumpData(pumpArray)
    setPumpState(false)
  }

  const handleContinue = () => {
    exportData = {
      city,
      pump,
      reading
    }
    if(city == null || pump == null || reading == null){
      setModalVisible(true)
    }else{
      navigation.navigate('Export', exportData)
    }
  };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
            }}>
            <View style={styles.modalView}>
              <Text style={styles.modalText}>PLEASE FILL ALL FIELDS!</Text>
              <Pressable
                style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
                onPress={(e) => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>OK</Text>
              </Pressable>
            </View>
          </Modal>
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.smallHeader}>
            CITY
          </Text>
          <Dropdown
            style={[styles.dropdown, isFocusCity && { borderColor: 'blue', borderWidth:2 }]}
            placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
            selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
            inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
            iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
            data={FireCityData}
            dropdownPosition='bottom'
            search
            maxHeight={300}
            labelField='label'
            valueField='value'
            placeholder={!isFocusCity ? 'Select city' : '...'}
            searchPlaceholder='Search...'
            value={city}
            onFocus={() => setIsFocusCity(true)}
            onBlur={() => setIsFocusCity(false)}
            onChange={item => {
              setCity(item.label);
              getCitysPumps(item)
              setIsFocusCity(false);
            }}
            renderLeftIcon={() => (
              <AntDesign
                style={styles.icon}
                color={isFocusCity ? 'blue' : 'black'}
                name='enviroment'
                size={hp('3%')}
              />
            )}
          />
      <Text style={[styles.smallHeader, isFocusCity && { color:'white'}]}>
        PUMP
      </Text>
      <Dropdown
            style={[styles.dropdown, isFocusPump && { borderColor: 'blue', borderWidth:2  }]}
            placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
            selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
            inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
            iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
            data={pumpData}
            search
            maxHeight={300}
            labelField='label'
            valueField='value'
            placeholder={!isFocusPump && city == null ? 'Select city to select pump' : !isFocusPump ? 'Select pump': '...'}
            searchPlaceholder='Search...'
            disable = {pumpState}
            value={pump}
            onFocus={() => setIsFocusPump(true)}
            onBlur={() => setIsFocusPump(false)}
            onChange={item => {
              setPump(item.label);
              setIsFocusPump(false);
            }}
            renderLeftIcon={() => (
              <AntDesign
                style={styles.icon}
                color={isFocusPump ? 'blue' : 'black'}
                name='tags'
                size={hp('3%')}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Text style={[styles.smallHeader, {marginTop:'5%'}]}>
            PUMP READING
          </Text>
          <TextInput
            style={[styles.inputContainer, {height: '15%',marginTop:'3%', color: '#ffffff'}]}
            placeholder='Enter the reading here'
            placeholderTextColor='#ffffff'
            textAlign='center'
            keyboardType='numeric'
            enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = {true}
            onChangeText={(reading) =>
              setReading(reading)
            }
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={handleContinue}
            style={styles.sucssesbutton}
          >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              CONTINUE
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  export default Readings;
```

[Selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDNPW.png)

[Items opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3HmB.png)
[Pressed on one of the items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJFUw.png)

I have tried to comment out useEffect but that was not the sollution